# Can anyone identify what type of weatherstripping this is?

Tags: weatherstripping

I'm fixing the bottom of my door which rotted out and part of that I think is because the bottom of the weatherstripping on the jam is damaged. I can't seem to find a match for this at HD, Lowes, or online. Maybe it came with the door when it was installed I don't know. But it seems to have a double section of tubing with a flat surface facing the door.

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: That looks to be magnetic. Try contacting a company that installs doors.

Comment: Something like this: https://mdbuildingproducts.com/product/steel-door-magnetic-weatherstrip-36-x-81/?  Is your door steel?

Comment: Oh interesting I had not thought of that, it is a metal clad door.  I'll see if something sticks to it.